# SwiftUI Store and Extract Dictionaries from UserDefaults.standard

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

So for Userdefaults.standard, I stored dictionaries for some keys, but I don't know how to access the values from it.

[image]

For those keys, value is supposed to be a dictionary, but I'm assuming the compiler doesn't know that. How would I loop over everything in my UserDefaults to find certain keys, and then access the dictionaries contained within them?

Answer (score 0):

DictionaryRepresentation returns a value of type `[String : Any]` so your `value` is of type `Any` and Any doesn't necessarily have a subscript operator. So you need to check what type it is and do a conditional down cast.

```
if let dict = value as? [String: Any] { ... }
```

But it may be a better idea not to use dictionaries to persist data. Consider instead making `ListItem` conform to `Codable` and then encode/decode a coded representation of ListItem directly.